# FormView Datakey Value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two web pages- the first is a `GridView` and the second is a `FormView`.  I have been able to retrieve the `DataKey` value from the `GridView` and pass it to the `FormView` page.  Now I need to use that key value for my selection query.  How do I assign that value?  Code example would help in C#.

This is my `page_load` code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string CompanyStr = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.QueryString["param1"]);
    string ClientKey = Request.QueryString["param2"];

    Label lbl = FormView1.FindControl("CompanyID") as Label;
    lbl.Text = CompanyStr;
 }
```

And this is the `FormView` code:

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DefaultMode="Insert" DataKeyNames="ClientKey"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" onitemcommand="onItemCommand">
```

The `ClientKey` is the variable that needs to be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use a Select Parameter in your `SQLDataSource1` markup (the one referenced in your `FormView` declaration) to do this.  This should work:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SQLDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="Your Connection Strong" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [yourTableName] WHERE ClientKey = @ClientKey">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ClientKey" QueryStringField="param2" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Notice the `WHERE` clause in the `SelectCommand` property.  I don't know what the rest of your query looks like, but having that on the end should filter your `FormView` down to what you want.

This should automatically pull the value from your query string, and your FormView will have the proper record loaded.

Comment: @Craig Glad to be of assistance!